# How can I join multiple teams with different rules?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want an *Iron Golem*, *Zombie A*, and *Zombie B* to be on a same team so they wouldn't attack each other but I want *Zombie B* to have a no collision rule. If I let *Zombie B* join another team with a `collisionRule` `never`, the *Iron Golem* can attack *Zombie B*.

I know that an entity can join only one team but I want to know if you know a work around for this problem.

Comment: Just to let you know, I tried to create a function that switches the zombie's team every tick. Did it work? Barely. It didn't attack for the first few seconds but then the iron golem gradually killed it. Also, the collision rule was a fail.